# What do the bars in ggdist::stat_halfeye() mean?

Tags: r, distributions, ggplot2

I am trying to understand what the black point, thicker horizontal bar, and thinner horizontal bar mean when I use the `stat_halfeye()` function. I can't find it on the [package website](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/). I'm pasting an example from my data below.

[image: Distribution plots]

Comment: Please read the [cheat sheets](https://github.com/mjskay/ggdist/blob/master/figures-source/cheat_sheet-slabinterval.pdf).

Comment: Is the relevant line, "Bins the CDF into an arbitrary number of intervals {here 66% and 95%)", meaning it contains 66% and 95% of the sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point and lines you are asking about is determined by the `point_interval` argument in the `ggdist::stat_halfeye` function. The default is "median_qi" meaning the point is the median and the plotted intervals are quantile intervals. The quantiles are determined by the `.width` argument, with the default being `c(.66, .95)`, meaning the thick line contains 66% of the density and the thinner line contains 95% of the density.

See [here](https://rdrr.io/github/mjskay/ggdist/man/stat_halfeye.html) for stat_halfeye documentation